# Cannot CSS rotate inner div when resizing outer div

Tags: jquery, css, coffeescript, rotation, css-transforms

This one has me stumped for days.  I have a simple setup.  Outer DIV, Inner DIV, image inside inner DIV.  I am trying to use CSS to rotate the inner div and then resize the outer div to the inner div's new dimensions.  This causes all sorts of problems.

Here is a JSFiddle showing what happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/h3M8r/

Click on Rotate Inner to see how the inner rotates perfectly fine when you don't touch the outer DIV dimensions.  Then re-run the fiddle and click on Rotate Inner + Outer and you get a mess.  The image rotates but the inner div does not.  The outer div resizes based on dimensions that arent even visible from the inner div.  AHHHHHHHhhhhhh!!

Here is the code:

```
#wrapper {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
width: 200px;
height: auto;    
border: 1px solid green;

#inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px dotted red;

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }            
}
}
```

and the js:

```
$('#rotate').click (ev) ->
    ev.preventDefault()

    $wrapper = $('#wrapper')
    $inner = $('#inner')

    rotation = $inner.data('rotation') + 90
    rotation = 0 if rotation >= 360

    $inner.data('rotation',rotation).css({'-webkit-transform': "rotate(#{rotation}deg)"})

$('#rotate_io').click (ev) ->
    ev.preventDefault()

    $wrapper = $('#wrapper')
    $inner = $('#inner')

    rotation = $inner.data('rotation') + 90
    rotation = 0 if rotation >= 360

    $inner.data('rotation',rotation).css({'-webkit-transform': "rotate(#{rotation}deg)"})

    dimensions = $inner.get(0).getBoundingClientRect()
    rotatedWidth = dimensions.width
    rotatedHeight = dimensions.height

    $wrapper.width(rotatedWidth).height(rotatedHeight)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What you want to do is not posible. There is no easy way, as far as I know, to retrieve the *transformed* dimensions of anything. Your only way, and not easy, would be to retrieve also the transform matrix, and do some *complex* math.

Comment: Getting the dimensions of the transformed image is simple.  The problem is that the inner won't rotate if the wrapper is resized.  Please see the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/h3M8r/1/

```
$('#rotate_io').click (ev) ->
    ev.preventDefault()

    $wrapper = $('#wrapper')

    rotation = $wrapper.data('rotation') + 90
    rotation = 0 if rotation >= 360

    $wrapper.data('rotation',rotation).css({'-webkit-transform': "rotate(#{rotation}deg)"})
```

If you are rotating the outer element you don't need to do anything with the inner element - it will rotate along with it's parent (outer) element.

Comment: Sorry but this is not what we're looking for.  We cannot rotate the wrapper since there are a number of other features tieda to that, such as jqueryui resizable and droppable.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was wrong, and you are getting the transformed dimension right.

The problem is another: when you say that the inner width is 100%, that means the inner width **before** the rotation is set to the width of the outer.

So the dimensions of the inner are set to the wrong values, and looks like it is not rotated (but if you look at the image, it **is** rotated.

The only way to solve this that I have find is to set the dimensions of the inner fixed.

When you solve that, there is another problem, that the rotation is no longer centered.

I have solved that using an old trick, to center it setting margin and top/left properties

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;    
    border: 1px solid green;

    #inner {
        width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -100px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -40px;
        border: 1px dotted red;
        position: absolute;

        img {
            width: 100%;
        }            
    }
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/h3M8r/2/)